# Web Api (mvc, asp.net), subscribe-push and long running tasks

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm working on a project that is to provide clients some views on relatively complex data. There are (at least) two ways to approach this task

1. Read data from db, "dump" it to client, let JS-client perform all calculations
2. Server side (C#) load data from DB, cook data suitable to "lightweight" JS-client (basically, cook data in a form D3 charts or DataTables would understand right away).

Approach (1) is totally valid, just not convinced that it really fits existing infrastructure at leas at the moment
At the moment Approach (2) is being implemented and it works as following
.html:

```
<table id="table1" ...></table>
<table id="table2" ...></table>
<table id="table3" ...></table>
<div id="chartX"/>
....
$(document).ready(function () {
//initialize a table directly with url to api call:
    $('#table1').dataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://app/api/methodZ?param=value',
            dataSrc: '',
        },
     });
// or do a call and initialize table(s)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://app/api/methodA?param1=value1&param2=value2',
        success: function (result) {
            populatetable2(result.table2Data);
            populatetable3(result.table3Data);
        },
    });
```

I'd say pretty standard approach. The issue is as following

1. API calls are cpu and time consuming
2. Some calls are parallelizable
3. There are too many of calls needed to fill client views of a single page
4. Some calls are dependant (say, there is api method methodA that is self-contained and time/cpu consuming, medthodB is also time/cpu consuming and needs as part of its logic to run methodA)

My idea would be as following:

1. Client calls only one method, like "subscribe"
2. Web API server-side starts a task in background and pushes (via SignalR) partial results
3. Client receives data and fills UI step-by-step

.html:

```
<table id="table1" ...></table>
<table id="table2" ...></table>
<table id="table3" ...></table>
<div id="chartX"/>
....
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
....
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://app/api/subscribe?paramA=valueA',
    }); 
});

WorkerControllerHub.client.OnDataAReady = function (data) {
   //fill UI 
}

WorkerControllerHub.client.OnDataBReady = function (data) {
   //fill UI 
}
...
WorkerControllerHub.client.OnComplete = function (iserror, message) {
   //nicely notify user if there is an error or all data is loaded
}
```

And server side would be kind of

```
WorkerControllerHub { /*SignalR hub*/ }
WorkerController
{
    private void doAsync(int paramA)
    {
        var dataA = calculateA(paramA);
        WorkerControllerHub.OnDataAReady(dataA);

        var dataB = calculateB(paramB, dataB);
        WorkerControllerHub.OnDataAReady(dataA); //

        WorkerControllerHub.OnComplete(...);
    }

    public void Subscribe(int paramA)
    {
         sumbitAsyncJob({task/async/... doAsync with paramA});
         and immediate return from controller call
    }
}
```

I would say, from my previous experience on C++ or Java server-side projects I did with distributed applications, it's relatively standard approach. (Because quite some calculateA, calculateB, ... are interconnected, it is actually a preferred way). However, reading SO, it seems that this is not the approach to take -- long-running async tasks are not fitting IIS+WebAPI+ASP.NET at its best.

Hence is my question -- are there architectural suggestions that tackle with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, I'll go with the calculations on the server side.

**Long running functions (jobs)**
I guess your *calculations* can be started:
 - **by the user** from the client, call an async void hub method that starts your job
 - **on a schedule** using something like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler). You can set up a schedule for the job

---

**SignalR Broadcasting**
Your clients can join different [groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) depending on what components that needs updating that page has.
You can implement something like a Broadcaster class (that will be called after the job is done) and send the data to the users.

```
public class Broadcaster
{
    private static void BroadcastToGroup(Data data, string groupName)
    {
        var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients;
        clients.Group(groupName).UpdateData(data);
    }

    private static void BroadcastToAll(Data data)
    {
        var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients;
        clients.All.UpdateData(data);
    }
}
```

---

**Concurrency**
One problem with the long running jobs you may have is that one instance of the job can start before the previous one can finish. This can cause an overhead for your server.
One way to fix this is using a job scheduler and set the jobs as non-reentrant. Again, look at [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler).

---

**Recycling**
If you say your calculations will take a while, you may have issues with the [IIS Process Recycling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx). Basically, every 29hours (by default), IIS tries to stop all problematic threads and may consider your job as one.
Read this [great article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is sound, you would just have client method that listens to a server method, and whenever you have a chunk of data, you can broadcast it to the client, and the client can manipulate and append the data to client side view. You do not even need to use more than one method, you can simply manipulate the data received on the client. You can either wait for all data to be returned, or append the data as needed on the client, or with a task continuation on the server that updates the data and organizes it before sending it to the client, and have the client overwrite the data as its received.